# Converter objetos: de sintaxe literal para tipos prototype

Tags: javascript, json

Dado um tipo definido em javascript, por exemplo:

```
var Point = (function () {
    function Point(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    Point.prototype.dist = function () {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.y + this.x * this.y);
    };
    return Point;
})();
```

Que pode ser usado dessa forma:

```
var p = new Point(10, 20);
console.log(p.dist());
```

Ou assim:

```
var p = new Point();
p.x = 10;
p.y = 20;
console.log(p.dist());
```

Existe uma maneira direta de converter um objeto que normalmente é retornado por JSON, ou declarado usando sintaxe literal dessa maneira:

```
var p = { x: 10, y: 20 };
```

Para o meu tipo `Point` que possui o método `dist()` sem utilizar *de = para*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A única maneira de trocar o protótipo de um objeto existente é com a propriedade não padrão [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), que na prática tem suporte muito bom. Na próxima versão do JavaScript (ECMAScript 6), haverá uma função `Object.setPrototypeOf` para isso. Mas hoje o jeito é fazer assim:

```
var p = { x: 10, y: 20 };
p.__proto__ = Point.prototype;
console.log(p.dist());
```

<sup>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3BAhB/)</sup>

Outra opção é invocar o método direto do local de origem:

```
console.log(Point.prototype.dist.call(p));
```

<sup>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EHmae/)</sup>

Comment: Irei utilizar: `p.__proto__ = Point.prototype;`. Além, disso pra conseguir um array seja convertido só iterando cada elemento ou existe alguma maneira diferente?

Comment: Se você tem um array com esses objetos dentro precisa sim iterar e atribuir o `__proto__` um por um.